# SELinux re-labeling problem while attempting to run OpenVPN

Tags: fedora, selinux, openvpn

I'm trying to run OpenVPN under Fedora 19 with selinux
(selinux-policy-targeted) in enforcing mode, and I'm running into an AVC
I'm not entirely sure how to handle.

Starting OpenVPN from the command line as root works fine, but starting it
via systemd (`systemctl start openvpn@vpcbridge`, where
`/etc/openvpn/vpcbridge.conf` exists) results in:

```
  ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tap0: Permission denied (errno=13)
```

And in `/var/log/audit`:

```
  type=AVC msg=audit(1376412420.435:60): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for
  pid=720 comm="openvpn" scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0
  tcontext=system_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0 tclass=tun_socket
```

For reference, here's the OpenVPN configuration:

```
port 1194
user openvpn
dev tap0
proto udp
secret vpcbridge.key
keepalive 10 120
persist-tun
persist-key
```

If I run `audit2allow`, I get a module file that looks like this:

```
  module openvpn 1.0;

  require {
        type openvpn_t;
        type ifconfig_t;
        class tun_socket relabelfrom;
  }

  #============= openvpn_t ==============
  allow openvpn_t ifconfig_t:tun_socket
  relabelfrom;
```

But loading that generates an error:

```
  # semodule -i openvpn.pp
  libsepol.print_missing_requirements: openvpn's global requirements were
  not met: type/attribute openvpn_t (No such file or directory).
  libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or
  directory).
  semodule:  Failed!
```

I'm not sure what to do with this error.

**Update**: As requested, the output of `seinfo -t ...`:

```
# seinfo -t | grep openvpn
   openvpn_tmp_t
   openvpn_unconfined_script_exec_t
   openvpn_status_t
   openvpn_etc_rw_t
   openvpn_var_lib_t
   openvpn_var_run_t
   openvpn_port_t
   openvpn_server_packet_t
   openvpn_etc_t
   openvpn_initrc_exec_t
   openvpn_var_log_t
   openvpn_unconfined_script_t
   openvpn_exec_t
   openvpn_t
   openvpn_client_packet_t
```

Comment: I renamed your question, the other one though funny wasn't really appropriate 8-).

Comment: Can you post the output of `seinfo -t | grep openvpn` for us? It would just be good to see if openvpn_t actually was defined.

Comment: @JoelDavis I've updated the question.  It appears that `openvpn_t` is defined.

Comment: I don't have a Fedora system right now to check with, but now that I'm reading this some time later "openvpn" as a name seems kind of generic. To the point where it's possible that the OpenVPN package itself might have a module named that for the type information that it adds when it gets installed. Does this still happen if you give the module a different name? Like `openvpn-tun` or something?

Comment: Ooo, interesting thought.  I will try that out.

Comment: I think you nailed it.  You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Fedora system right now to check with, but now that I'm reading this some time later "openvpn" as a name seems kind of generic. To the point where it's possible that the OpenVPN package itself might have a module named that for the type information that it adds when it gets installed. Does this still happen if you give the module a different name? Like `openvpn-tun` or something?

I'm not 100% sure on the nitty-gritty details (this is basically just a wild guess) but it seems like it would create a conflict if the two modules had the same name. Especially if one module *depended* on information that was in the other.

**EDIT:**

Finally got home. Looks like there is a native SELinux module with that name:

```
[root@localhost test]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
[root@localhost test]# semodule -l | grep openvpn
openvpn 1.11.0
```

But it looks like I was wrong about how SELinux on Fedora works. It looks like it all comes in under a single policy package for the entire distribution:

```
[root@localhost modules]# pwd
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules
[root@localhost modules]# ls -lh openvpn.pp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12K Jun 27 08:59 openvpn.pp
[root@localhost modules]# rpm -qf $PWD/openvpn.pp
selinux-policy-targeted-3.11.1-98.fc18.noarch
```