# openvpn[]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file

Tags: centos, selinux, openvpn

when trying to `service openvpn start`

```
Oct 12 14:02:01 ccushing1 openvpn[9091]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: devnet-client-vm.conf
```

running `openvpn devnet-client-vm.conf` works just fine. Why does openvpn not start? how can I fix it?

Comment: I provided an answer, but I encourage answers that don't involve neutering SELinux

Answer (score 17):

You might want to run

```
fixfiles -R openvpn restore
```

An ls -alZ should give you something like this (showing your files are in the correct selinux context now):

```
[root@server openvpn]# ls -alZ /etc/openvpn/
drwxr-xr-x. root    root    system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root    root    system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       ..
drwxr-xr-x. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 certs
-rw-r--r--. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 dh2048.pem
drwxr-xr-x. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 easy-rsa
-rw-------. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_rw_t:s0 ipp.txt
-rw-------. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 ta.key
-rw-------. openvpn openvpn unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 server.conf
```

If you have a statement like

```
status openvpn-status.log
```

in your openvpn config file, you might notice the server still won't start. A peek at the /var/log/audit/audit.log will reveal

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1413580155.710:1265): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=19725 comm="openvpn" name="openvpn-status.log" dev="dm-1" ino=54153273 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Changing the context of this file to rw does the trick:

```
chcon -t openvpn_etc_rw_t openvpn-status.log
```

and

```
[root@server openvpn]# ls -alZ openvpn-status.log
-rw-------. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 openvpn-status.log
```

will become

```
-rw-------. root    root    unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_rw_t:s0 openvpn-status.log
```

Afterwards the call

```
service openvpn@server start
```

worked flawlessly.

```
[root@server openvpn]# service openvpn@server status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  openvpn@server.service
openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-10-17 23:13:49 CEST; 9s ago
  Process: 20445 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20449 (openvpn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service
           └─20449 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/server.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config server.conf

Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20445]: ROUTE_GATEWAY xx.xxx.xx.x/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: GID set to nobody
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: UID set to nobody
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Oct 17 23:13:49 server systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Oct 17 23:13:49 server openvpn[20449]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

PS: I'm on Centos 7.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I used to copy the files as regular user to /tmp/<someting>, then move them into place as root. That is how they go the wrong selinux context. *copying* them as root solves the problem, too; they then get the (right) selinux context.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else that finds this thread, I had the problem on Fedora 26. Turns out the instructions I was following had you put the conf files in /etc/openvpn directory, but they need to go in /etc/openvpn/server.

Comment: THANK YOU. For others that have to go this deep: You have to copy your `ca`, `crt` and `key` (so two `.crt` files and a `.key`) file to the same directory

Comment: This was also the solution for me on CentOS 8

Comment: This should be the resolving answer. Tysm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is SELinux, editing `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and setting `SELINUX=permissive` and then rebooting fixed it for me. I remember in fedora that there was a command that had to be run to allow the cert directory to be used properly, but I forget what that command is. Setting to permissive fixes completely but a more preferred way would be to fix it so that it can use the directory properly.

Answer (score 0):

For the cert directory and the SElinux issue, seems that's quite old, first reported here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=555785
And seems it's an upstream bug, at least when you use NetworkManager to control your openvpn connection. But the upstream bug is still "unconfirmed" -.-
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670198

Maybe [SELinux re-labeling problem while attempting to run OpenVPN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/selinux-re-labeling-problem-while-attempting-to-run-openvpn) helps somehow with the SElinux bits.

Or if you want to use per-user certificates, and not systemwide ones: https://superuser.com/questions/339391/making-selinux-play-nice-with-openvpn-in-networkmanager

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above error by moving the conf file(s)
to the `client` directory, e.g.,

```
/etc/openvpn/client/openvpn.conf
```

Comment: @GAD3R: Huh?  It appears to me that this *does* provide an answer to the question; every bit as much as [Jeremiah’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411183/80216#578089), which is similar (but not identical).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error that is mentioned in the header since I had mistyped the name of the ovpn file, typing opvn instead. Better always use the tab trick to complete writing the name of a file.

```
sudo openvpn MY_FILE.ovpn
```

*Side-note: This works, but in my case, it did not help me, my DBMS still could not reach the databases of an external network. Instead, I had to go to Linux "Network Settings", click on the "+" to create a new VPN connection, and choose to import from file and select MY_FILE.ovpn.*

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem For me Also The issue was I was not in the vpn.ovpn File Directory

1)Check Your Directory (sudo openvpn vpn.ovpn)
2)if Not Solved Do This -> sudo killall openvpn
3) Again Try To Connect [sudo openvpn [file.name]
4) Redownload The File if Possible. Some Times Ovpn Files also May Have issues

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).